# The method 'map' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart-null-safety

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6CiU.png)

there is error with the map even when i add .toList() to the map

Comment: provide source code as text please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that map((note) => Text(note.title)) can potentially be null.

If you are sure that you will always have items in notes, use the "!" to tell the compiler that it won't be null:

```
final children = notes.map((note) => Text(note.title))!.toList();
```